# Django channels: How to reference ForeignKey and their fields in async context?

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, django-channels

I am right now converting a couple of Websocket-Handlers from WebsocketConsumer to AsyncWebsocketConsumer. There is one line that causes problems. The Sync version was:

```
self.mydatacache['workernr'] = school.objects.get(id=myschool).tf_worker.id
```

My first try for an async version was this:

```
self.mydatacache['workernr'] = await school.objects.aget(id=myschool).tf_worker.id
```

Second try:

```
school_object = await school.objects.aget(id=myschool)
tf_worker_object = await school_object.tf_worker   
self.mydatacache['workernr'] = tf_worker_object.id
```

I tried many variations of this, but I always got the same error:

```
You cannot call this from an async context
```

I must be on the completely wrong track here. Any suggestions?

PS: I am aware of database_sync_to_async. If possible I would like to avoid that...

Comment: Accessing the foreign key `school_object.tf_worker` is triggering a sync query, you should be able to do a single async query from the worker model, something like this `worker_object = await WorkerModel.objects.aget(school__id=myschool)`

Comment: @Iain Shelvington : That solved the problem. Thanks...

Comment: @Iain Shelvington : ...though I do not really understand why this works. For my understanding 
`await WorkerModel.objects.aget(school__id=myschool)`
will translate to SQL like this:
`SELECT * FROM workermodel WHERE school_id = [myschool]`
which does not make much sense to me because the table workermodel has no school or school_id column. Still the proposed code works. This is kind of reversed. Could someone please enlighten me?